# Returning an array reference to a method

Tags: java, object

I have to create a method which takes an integer parameter and returns an 
array of that many references to deck objects created by calling `generateCard()`.

here is what I wrote:

```
int [] generateDeckOfNCards(int n) { 
    int [] generateDeckOfNCards = new int[n]; 
    return generateDeckOfNCards; 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't they be Card objects returned from a method called "createCard"?

Answer (score 3):

You should declare an array of `DeckCard` objects (not `int`s), and populate it.

Something among the lines of:

```
DeckCard[] generateDeckOfNCards(int n) { 
    DeckCard[] res = new DeckCard[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = generateCard(); //assuming such a method exists. 
    }
    return res; 
}
```